# Combination of combobox and input type in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, razor

I'm creating a form that requires a combination of `DropDownList` and text `input` controls.  I'm currently using Razor as a template in our web page.

Here's my Razor `DropDownList` snippet:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PredictorRegionDesc, Model.PredictorRegionDescs, "Please select a Region", new { @class = "form-control" })%>                      
</div>
```

this results in a `DropDownList` appearing: 
[image: DropDownList Result]

Now, I need to convert this to a combination of `DropDownList` and text `input`.

Whenever the user doesn't see the data he/she wants in the `DropDownList`, user will have the ability to input new data in the test `input`.

I have seen `DataList` as an example of what I want, but it seems that it cannot be done using razor. I've also looked at some js plugins, but it doesn't do what I want. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `input type` isn't really descriptive.. I suppose you mean `textbox` or `text input`?  it also seems like you're saying the user will select a specific option in the dropdown, and the text input will display and be a required input for the form?

Comment: My bad, I meant Text Input. User can both input text or select from a list of options. Please see HTML Datalist it has the same function, but I cannot use it while using Razor as a template. Thanks.

Comment: so, you're saying the Text Input will also be visible, and the value of which is **NOT** limited to what is in the `DropDownList`, thus selecting anything in the `DropDownList` will populate the Text Input.  does typing into the text input filter what appears in the `DropDownList`?..

Comment: seems like this is a standard [typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) usage

Comment: Hi Brett thanks for recommending typeahead but It seems that my dataset are unable to link to it. Do you somehow know if there's an equivalent Razor code for this? I'm also trying to use JSON to send the data from the model to my dropdown list but it seems that it doesn't work.

Comment: Here's my try on getting the data from Market(one of my combo boxes)

$.getJSON( "Market", function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        });